Getting location from Cell towers or WiFi only
Without going to politics my country currently jamming GPS locations due to war. On google maps and other location app I see myself in other country. So I need to know my location from Cell or WiFi tower.
I tried using:
setPriority(LocationRequest.QUALITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY)
setPriority(LocationRequest.QUALITY_LOW_POWER)

For example:
suspend fun getCurrentLocation(): Location? = suspendCoroutine { cont ->
  Log.d(TAG, "Getting current location")

  val locationRequest = CurrentLocationRequest.Builder().setDurationMillis(2500)
    .setPriority(LocationRequest.QUALITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
    .build()

  val cancellationToken = CancellationTokenSource().token
  val fusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(MyApp.appContext)

  fusedLocationClient.getCurrentLocation(locationRequest, cancellationToken)
    .addOnSuccessListener {
      cont.resume(it)
      Log.d(TAG, "Resuming $it")
    }
    .addOnFailureListener { e: Exception ->
      cont.resume(null)
      Log.e(TAG, "Failed: $e")
    }
}

Without success, also jammed.
For this code:
@SuppressLint("MissingPermission", "ServiceCast")
suspend fun getCurrentLocationCell(): Location? = suspendCoroutine { cont ->
  var context = MyApp.appContext

  val telephonyManager = context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE) as TelephonyManager
  val allCellInfo = telephonyManager.allCellInfo

  if (allCellInfo.isNotEmpty()) {
    val cellInfo: CellInfo = allCellInfo[0] // Assuming the first one is the active cell
    val location = Location(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER).apply {
      when (cellInfo) {
        is android.telephony.CellInfoLte -> {
          // Extract LTE Cell Identity
          val cellIdentity = cellInfo.cellIdentity
          // For example, use cellIdentity.ci, cellIdentity.pci, etc., to estimate location
        }
        is android.telephony.CellInfoWcdma -> {
          // Extract WCDMA Cell Identity
          val cellIdentity = cellInfo.cellIdentity
          // Use cellIdentity.lac, cellIdentity.cid, etc.
        }
        is android.telephony.CellInfoGsm -> {
          // Extract GSM Cell Identity
          val cellIdentity = cellInfo.cellIdentity
          // Use cellIdentity.lac, cellIdentity.cid, etc.
        }
        is android.telephony.CellInfoNr -> {
          // Extract NR (5G) Cell Identity
          val cellIdentity = cellInfo.cellIdentity
          // Use cellIdentity.nci, cellIdentity.pci, etc.
        }
        // Add more cases if you handle other cell types
      }
      // Example location
      latitude = 0.0
      longitude = 0.0
      accuracy = 1000f
    }
    cont.resume(location)
  } else {
    cont.resume(null)
  }
}


Error
java.lang.SecurityException: Not allowed to access cell info
althow I have this permissions:

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />

Any suggestions?

"I tried using" -- I recommend providing more code around that first section, showing your complete request for locations.

Adding my code.

You are using the fused location provider, which is supposed to blend GPS with other sources. If you do not want GPS, you might try not using the fused location provider, instead using LocationManager and avoiding GPS_PROVIDER.

Have to ask the obvious, did you grant the permissions? It's not good enough to just add the permissions to the manifest.

@TGruenwald I granted them manually from app info in settings, for testing only. I did not added user prompt.

Are you using satellite for internet and phone service? This could make location gathering difficult.

@TGruenwald No satellite for internet and phone service, the GSM is working fine.

I fear that in areas where GPS is unreliable Assisted GPS base station dependency on GPS almanac data would also become unreliable such that you are limited to the very coarse IP address location. Google's internal database of WiFi locations for Fused Locations also may age out/need updates without verified GPS position (see reports of moving a home WiFi base station from one location to a different US state and seeing the "old home" location until Google updates).

Does the target device have internet or phone service? If GPS is jammed, the options of location are IP address or using the location of the connection points for internet or phone service.
